# TypeError: tagGroupString.split is not a function + node.js +cucumber

Tags: node.js, cucumber, protractor

I am getting below error when trying to execute the tests. I am using grunt-protractor-cucumber 0.6.0, protractor 3.2.2 - node 4.4, npm 3.8.8, typings 0.6.8,

I am using Windows OS

**[launcher] Error: TypeError: tagGroupString.split is not a function
   at Array.map (native)
   at Array.filter (native)
[launcher] Process exited with error code 100**

Above function is in **cucumber-js/lib/cucumber/tag_group_parser.js**

```html
function TagGroupParser(tagGroupString) {
  var self = {
    parse: function parse() {
      var splitTags = tagGroupString.split(TagGroupParser.TAG_SEPARATOR);
      var trimmedTags = splitTags.map(function (tag) { return tag.trim(); });
      return trimmedTags;
    }
  };
  return self;
}

TagGroupParser.getTagGroupsFromStrings = function getTagGroupsFromStrings(tagGroupStrings) {
  var Cucumber = require('../cucumber');

  var tagGroups = tagGroupStrings.map(function (tagOptionValue) {
    var tagGroupParser = Cucumber.TagGroupParser(tagOptionValue);
    var tagGroup       = tagGroupParser.parse();
    return tagGroup;
  });
  return tagGroups;
};

TagGroupParser.TAG_SEPARATOR = ',';

module.exports = TagGroupParser;
```

Comment: it errors even if I run dry report.. I pasted tag_group_parser.js file in to my question

Comment: can you show how you call `TagGroupParser` function? What is the value of the variable you pass in as `tagGroupString`?

Comment: As of now we are not calling that any where but that function comes along with core cucumber framework. it's in GIT as well.  Looks like it's a bug with npm 3.8.8 on Windows  after I down graded to 2.15, it worked with out issues..

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it's a bug with npm 3.8.8 on Windows , it works fine on Mac. After down graded to 2.15, it worked fine.